# Renderscript error in Android Studio 2.0 stable

Tags: android-studio, renderscript, android-studio-2.0

I updated Android Studio to 2.0 stable, then I got this error:

> Renderscript support mode is not currently supported with renderscript
>   target 21+

What should i do?
tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renderscript isn't currently supported with Target 21+ so simply change the target to below API 20 and that error will be solved.
replace your code with below code:

```
renderscriptTargetApi 20
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in gradle-plugin 2.1.0 and Build-Tools 23.0.3.
Use the code below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    ...
}
```